# Pause CRM 2013 workflow for 5 minutes issue

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

In my workflow i have to implement the logic for pausing the workflow for 5 mniutes.  i have written the below code.

```
var query = new QueryExpression("asyncoperation");
query.ColumnSet.AllColumns = true;
query.Criteria = new FilterExpression();
query.Criteria.AddCondition(new ConditionExpression("name", ConditionOperator.Equal, "workflowname"));

var results = crmService.RetrieveMultiple(query);
var rerunworkflow = results.Entities.FirstOrDefault();

Entity operation = new Entity("asyncoperation") {  Id = rerunworkflow.GetAttributeValue<Guid>("asyncoperationid") };
operation["postponeuntil"] = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5);
operation["statecode"] = new OptionSetValue(1);
operation["statuscode"] = new OptionSetValue(10);
crmService.Update(operation);
```

But, when this workflow is activated and  it is called, it is showing me below error.  The state transition requested is not valid for the current state. Current state: 3, current status: 30, target state: 1.   Why this issue is occur? It was previously possible in crm 4.0 and now it is showing that workflow in completed status.  Please Guid on the same.  Thanks,  Kandarp

Comment: Please, format your question by indenting your code so we can understand it...

Comment: Why not just use the CRM Workflow Timeout/Wait functionality instead of using custom code? How do you ensure that the `asyncoperation` record you retrieved is of the currently executing workflow?

Answer (score 0):

Please see the answer on this page:
https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/p/157381/372199.aspx#372199

```
 Entity dynamicEntity = GetAsyncOperationInfo(crmService, context.OperationId);
 // update the AsyncOperation as suspended (10) postponed of 5 minutes
 Entity asyncOperation = new Entity("asyncoperation");
 asyncOperation.Id = context.OperationId;
 asyncOperation["statecode"] = new OptionSetValue(10);
 asyncOperation["postponeuntil"] = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5);
 crmService.Update(asyncOperation);
 if (dynamicEntity != null && dynamicEntity.Contains("createdon"))
 {
   DateTime createdon = ((DateTime)dynamicEntity["createdon"]);
   TimeSpan span = DateTime.UtcNow - createdon; 
 // note the UtcNow instead the `Now, this because createdon from CRM comes as UTC
   if (span.Minutes < 30)
   {
       System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0));
   }
}
```